# can't find icons (beginner)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, element-ui

I'm using [ElementUI](http://element.eleme.io/2.0/#/en-US/component/custom-theme) everything works fine but the icons is not showing.

On my console i have an error 404 for the following url

```
http://localhost/fonts/vendor/element-ui/lib/theme-chalk/element-icons.woff?2fad952a20fbbcfd1bf2ebb210dccf7a

http://localhost/fonts/vendor/element-ui/lib/theme-chalk/element-icons.ttf?6f0a76321d30f3c8120915e57f7bd77e
```

based on their documentation i've done the following. ([updating scss variables](http://element.eleme.io/2.0/#/en-US/component/custom-theme))

```
/* theme color */
$--color-primary: teal;

/* icon font path, required */
$--font-path: '~element-ui/lib/theme-chalk/fonts';

@import "~element-ui/packages/theme-chalk/src/index";
```

I updated the variables, the `$--color-primary: teal;` works fine but the font path is still getting an error

Im using it on Laravel 5.6 with vue js

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Webpack then you might look Webpack configuration. You might check the following settings,

[Element-starter - Webpack config](https://github.com/ElementUI/element-starter/blob/master/webpack.config.js)